# How to link a QPushButton to a tab of QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtabwidget

I am using Qt to do a GUI program, so my problem is, I have made a homepage in my GUI program and I have some 4 tabs tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4 and I have made QPushbutton over at homepage. So can anyone tell me how can I link QPushButton to tab3 of QTabWidget so that when I click the button it should take me to tab 3. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a slot, what handles the buttons click event ([Slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html), [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpushbutton.html))
Then use the QTabWidgets [setCurrentIndex](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) function like `yourTabWidget->setCurrentIndex(2);`

Comment: It is a little bit nice to use `setCurrentWidget()` instead of `setCurrentIndex()` so you don't have to pass some random number but instead the actual tab widget to show.

Comment: Can you please edit your and provide me code of it to understand? I am very new to Qt.

Comment: You are wellcome! If you want to create Gui applications, keep using Qt. If you get used to C++, the functionality what both the Gui and Core part offers, is really good.