# How to add a "new tab" on an existing QTabWidget using a QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I am trying to add a "new tab" on an existing `QTabWidget` using a `QPushButton` as shown below:

[image: tab]

**The problem** I have is that as I push the button nothing happens and no "new tab" is added. 
I set all the proper connection and slots but something is preventing me from adding it to the `QTabWidget`. Basically nothing happens as I push the button.

Below the minimal verifiable example:

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void newTab();

private slots:
    void on_addTabBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tabWidget->clear();
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QLabel("+"), QString("+"));
    connect(ui->tabWidget, &QTabWidget::currentChanged, this, &MainWindow::on_addTabBtn_clicked);
    newTab();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::newTab()
{
    int position = ui->tabWidget->count() - 1;
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(position, new QLabel("Insert New Tab"), QString("New Tab"));
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(position);
    auto tabBar = ui->tabWidget->tabBar();
    tabBar->scroll(tabBar->width(), 0);
}


void MainWindow::on_addTabBtn_clicked()
{
    int index = 0;
    if(index == this->ui->tabWidget->count() - 1) {
        newTab();
    }
}
```

In case you would also like to see the simple `.ui` file see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>428</width>
    <height>279</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 1</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 2</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="addTabBtn">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Add Tab</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>428</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I tried to solve the problem in many ways and researched what the cause might be. I came across several references such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867016/how-to-link-a-qpushbutton-to-a-tab-of-qtabwidget), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699241/how-to-add-a-tab-to-qtabwidget-using-the-button-on-the-form) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975137/how-can-i-add-a-new-tab-button-next-to-the-tabs-of-a-qmdiarea-in-tabbed-view-m) but none of them helped to completely solve the problem.

I am sure that the property of [currentChanged](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtabwidget.html#currentChanged) is correct, however the callback to trigger the button is not doing the job despite there are no errors in the terminal.

What am I missing? Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect` the `clicked` signal of the button to the `addTab` function/slot of the tabwidget (or to an intermediate function/lambda that calls `addTab` on the correct destination object).

For example:

```
connect(ui->addTabBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [&] { ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QLabel("+"), QString("+")); });
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Hi and thanks for reading the question :) . Could you please integrate your answer with a but of code?

Comment: If that is what you mean `connect(ui->tabWidget, &QTabWidget::addTab, this, &MainWindow::on_addTabBtn_clicked);` it is not working, it says that `no matching member function for call to connect`

Comment: Ooooo Ok I know what you mean.Thanks for updating the answer. It works correctly :) Thanks for your time!